# Convert custom label string to set in Aura controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, customlabel, set

I have a custom label `Restriced_Profiles`, which contains a comma-separated string of Profile Names - `Profile A, Profile B , System Administrator`

In the aura controller, I am trying to convert this string to a set so that I can check if the logged-in user profile contains in the set.

Problem: I tried using split to convert the string to set but when I print it in the console it still shows as a string. So unable to do a .has test on this. Below is the code:

```
    let prfiles = $A.get("$Label.c.Restriced_Profiles");
    let setOfProfiles = prfiles.split(",");
    console.log('setOfProfiles ------->' + setOfProfiles); // It still shows `Profile A, Profile B , System Administrator`
```

It appears that split is not converting it from string to set. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `+`, and a string `+` an object calls `toString()` on that object, which for an Array, causes the elements to be converted into a comma separated string of values:

```
let output = ''+['a','b','c'];
console.log(output); //'a,b,c'
```

Instead, use the comma operator:

```
console.log('setOfProfiles ------->', setOfProfiles);
```

Which will output an object you can inspect with all the values.

Note that you still don't have a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), you have an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You can:

```
let setOfProfiles = new Set($A.get("$Label.c.Restricted_Profiles").split(","));
```

The moral of the story is that you should be careful when using `+` as a string concatenation, both in JavaScript and Apex, because you may get "unexpected" output in the debug logs.

Comment: Thank you for an insightful answer.